# Parser with LEX and YACC

Tags: c, yacc, lex

i'm trying to implement a time parser with LEX & YACC.
I'm a complete newbie to those tools and C programming.

The program has to print a message (*Valid time format 1: input* ) when one of those formats is entered: **4pm, 7:38pm, 23:42, 3:16, 3:16am,** otherwise a *"Invalid character"* message is printed.

lex file **time.l** :

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%

[0-9]+                {yylval=atoi(yytext); return digit;}
"am"                   { return am;}
"pm"                   { return pm;}
[ \t\n]               ;
[:]                    { return colon;}
.                     { printf ("Invalid character\n");}

%%
```

yacc file **time.y**:

```
%{
void yyerror (char *s);
int yylex();
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

%}

%start time
%token digit
%token am
%token pm
%token colon

%%

time        :  hour ampm           {printf ("Valid time format 1 : %s%s\n ", $1, $2);}
            |  hour colon minute   {printf ("Valid time format 2 : %s:%s\n",$1, $3);}
            |  hour colon minute ampm {printf ("Valid time format 3 : %s:%s%s\n",$1, $3, $4); }
            ;

ampm        :   am               {$$ = "am";}
            |   pm               {$$ = "pm";}
            ;

hour        :   digit digit             {$$ = $1 * 10 + $2;}
            |   digit             { $$ = $1;}
            ;

minute      :   digit digit         {$$ =  $1 * 10 + $2;} 
            ;

%%
int yywrap()
{
        return 1;
} 

int main (void) {

  return yyparse();
}

void yyerror (char *s) {fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);}
```

compiling with this command:

```
yacc -d time.y && lex time.l && cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o time
```

I'm getting some warnings:

```
time.y:17:47: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
      'YYSTYPE' (aka 'int') [-Wformat]
    {printf ("Valid time format 1 : %s%s\n ", (yyvsp[(1) - (2)]), (yyvsp.
```

This warning appears for all the variables in printf statements.
The values are all char, because even the number in the time string is converted with the `atoi` function.

Executing the program with a valid input throws this error:

```
./time

1pm

[1]    2141 segmentation fault  ./time
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (f)lex rule:

```
[0-9]+                {yylval=atoi(yytext); return digit;}
```

recognizes any integer, not just a digit. (It allows leading zeros, which is probably appropriate for a date parser.) It assumes that `yylval` is an `int`, which is the case if you don't do something to declare the type of `yylval`.

Meanwhile, this (f)lex rule:

```
"am"                 { return am;}
```

recognizes the token `am`, but does not set the value of `yylval`.

Now, in your bison file, you have:

```
hour        :   digit digit       { $$ = $1 * 10 + $2; }
            |   digit             { $$ = $1;}
            ;
```

Since `digit` actually represents an entire integer, the `digit digit` production is incorrect. It would recognize, for example, the input `23 75` (since your flex file ignores whitespace), but it would turn that into the value 305 (10*23 + 75). That hardly seems appropriate. Again, it assumes that the type of the semantic values `$$` and `$1` is `int`, which is the default case.

However, the production:

```
ampm        :   am               {$$ = "am";}
            |   pm               {$$ = "pm";}
            ;
```

requires that the type of the result semantic value be `char *` (or even `const char*`). Since you have not done anything to declare the type of semantic values, their type is `int` and the assignment is just as invalid as would be the C statement:

```
int ampm = "am";
```

So the C compiler issues an error message.

Furthermore, in your production:

```
time        :  hour ampm           {printf ("Valid time format 1 : %s%s\n ", $1, $2);}
```

you assume that the semantic values `$1` and `$2` are strings (`char*`). BUt the values are actually integers, so `printf` will do something undefined and probably disastrous (in this case, segfault). (Because of the nature of C this is not a compile-time error, but most C compilers will issue a warning. Apparently, your C compiler does so.)

How this should be fixed depends on your interpretation of the assignment. When it says "print a message (*Valid time format 1: input* )", does it mean that the literal input string should be printed, or is it ok to print an interpretation of the string? That is, given actual inputs

```
8:23am
08:23am
```

Would you want the messages to be

```
Valid time format 1: 8:23am
Valid time format 1: 08:23am
```

Or is it appropriate to normalize:

```
Valid time format 1: 8:23am
Valid time format 1: 8:23am
```

You should (re-)read the section in the [`bison` manual on semantic types](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Semantics), and then decide whether you want the type to be `int`, `char*`, or a union of the two.

Some other things you need to think about:

1. Your flex file recognizes any integer, but neither hours nor minutes can be arbitrary integers. Both are limited to two digits; normally, the minutes should always be two digits (so that `9:3am` is *not* a way of writing `9:03am`). They both have limited ranges of valid values; minutes must be between `00` and `59`, while hours is between 1 and 12 if am or pm is specified, and otherwise between 0 and 23. Or perhaps 24. (Actually, there are lots of different possible validity conventions for hours; you might choose to be flexible or strict.)
2. Your problem description doesn't appear to allow spaces in the time specifications, but your flex file ignores whitespace. So that might lead you to recognize incorrect inputs (depending, again, on how strict you wish to be). Also see the note about output in this case: does the whitespace appear in the output (assuming it is acceptable)?
3. Your flex file issues an error message when it sees a character it doesn't recognize, but it does not stop lexing. In effect, that means that illegal characters will be dropped from the input stream, so that an input like:

   ```
   1;:17rpm
   ```

   will result in two illegal character messages followed by a message saying that the input was a valid `1:17pm`. That is unlikely to be what you wanted.

As a final note, I have to say that in my opinion, understanding C is an absolute prerequisite to using flex and bison. Trying to teach all three at the same time strikes me as pedagogically suspect.

Comment: I will answer my question with the final version of the lex file.

And yes, is true, trying to learn C with lex and yacc all at once is not the best learning process.
I'm reading the Pragmatic Programmer, and this was an exercise from the book.
I only learned the things that helped me to implement a program that solves the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
time.y:17:47: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
  'YYSTYPE' (aka 'int') [-Wformat]
```

for that line for example

```
printf ("Valid time format 1 : %s%s\n ", $1, $2);
```

says that you specified an `%s` (which is a C-style string of type `char *`) but effectively the argument is of type `YYSTYPE` (which seems to be an integer type).

Answer (score 0):

As @Elyasin pointed out, the error message you're given is telling you exactly what's wrong- YYSTYPE defaults to being an int but you're attempting to use it as a string (this is on every line you get the error).  Furthermore you're attempting to use it as an int in some places and a string in others, which is obviously incorrect.

What you can do is create a string to hold your input as you go and concatenate into that.  You can do this with a variable in your initial yacc block, so something like this:

```
%{
void yyerror (char *s);
int yylex();
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char time_str[15];
%}
```

time_str is now available throughout your parser steps, so you can copy into that, then in your final step you can just print out the built up string, like

```
printf ("Valid time format 1 : %s", timestr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the warnings defining a char array for am and pm values and treated as int the `YYSTYPE` variables (as suggested).

I've also added cases for empty lines, comma separation after each input, validation for hours and minutes, exit command:

```
%{
void yyerror (char *s);
int yylex();
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char ampm_str[15] = "";

typedef int bool;
bool validFormat = 1;
%}

%start input
%token digit
%token am
%token pm
%token colon
%token sep
%token exit_command

%%
input       : /* empty */
            | input line 
            ;

line        : '\n'
            | list '\n' 
            ;

list        : time
            | time sep list 
            | exit_command  {exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
            ;


time        :  hour ampm                {if ($1 > 12 || $1 <= 0)  {printf ("Hour out of range\n");validFormat = 0;} else if(validFormat) {printf("Valid time format %d%s\n", $1, ampm_str); } validFormat = 1;}
            |  hour colon minute        {if ($1 > 24 || $1 <= 0)  {printf ("Hour out of range\n");validFormat = 0;} else if(validFormat) {printf("Valid time format   %d:%d\n", $1, $3); } validFormat = 1;}
            |  hour colon minute ampm   {if ($1 > 12 || $1 <= 0)  {printf ("Hour out of range\n");validFormat = 0;} else if(validFormat) {printf ("Valid time format   %d:%d%s\n", $1, $3, ampm_str); } validFormat = 1;}
            ;


hour        :   two_digits        { $$ = $1; }
            |   digit             { $$ = $1; }
            ;

minute      :   two_digits          { $$ = $1; if ($$ > 59) {printf ( "minute out of range\n");validFormat = 0;}}
            |   digit               { $$ = $1; if ($$ > 59) {printf ( "minute out of range\n");validFormat = 0;}}
            ;

two_digits  :  digit digit          {$$ = 0; $$ = $1 * 10 + $2; }
            ;

ampm        :   am               {strcpy(ampm_str, "am");}
            |   pm               {strcpy(ampm_str, "pm");}
            ;


%%
int yywrap()
{
        return 1;
} 

int main (void) {
printf ("Insert time, and press enter\n");
printf ("Type , after each time\n");
printf ("Valid formats : 2am, 12:00, 13:30pm\n");
printf ("exit to quit\n");

  return yyparse();
}


void yyerror (char *s) {fprintf (stderr, "Invalid character: %s\n", s); validFormat = 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

For byte parsing
in lex file
0x[0-9a-f]{8}   { yylval.number = strtoll(yytext+2, NULL, 16); return BYTE_4; }
In yacc file
You need to declear this number as part of union.

Comment: For ward below can be used

Comment: For ward parsing [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_\+]* { yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return WORD; }

Comment: You can just edit your post. No need to add things in comment.